# Xcode MapView Set Pins With Button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dictionary, pins

I am trying to make an application that requires the user to log their current location, then have the pin stay there. So if I had a map view I would have a mapview and then a button on the bottom of the screen, allowing the user to place a pin where their current location is.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapview setRegion:[self.mapview regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

    // Add an annotation
    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
    point.title = @"Where am I?";
    point.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";

    [self.mapview addAnnotation:point];
}
```

I have used that code to place a pin where my current location is, but I need that to happen after a button is tapped. I also need that pin to stay where they tapped it, so If they move ater on the pin will stay where they tapped it.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: So just call your location manager startUpdatingLocation after pressing the button?

Comment: Would I just call it like this?    [self mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation];                Sorry I am new

Comment: No, it is a delegate that should not be called directly. Try to call set self.mapView.showsUserLocation=YES; after the button is pressed.

Comment: Okay thanks! But that only does my current location. How do I place a pin there, and then keep the pin there? Thanks!

Comment: Somehow I need to call (MKUserLocation *)userLocation in my Action, so i can use the statement userLocation.

Comment: I thought your code will place the pin. After the pin is placed, just change the property showsUserLocation to NO.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31444/discussion-between-verbumdei-and-nicholas-gibson)